# How can i change the value of an attribute of an asset using a transaction?

Tags: javascript, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I am working on hyperledger composer playground.I have an asset which has details of a customer:

```
{
    "$class": "org.example.empty.userData",
    "id": "3890",
    "Name": "Ramesh",
    "Data": [
        "disease",
        "some more disease"
    ],
    "category": "Health",
    "Mobile": "8698617174",
    "timestamp": "2019-01-03T11:26:50.915Z",
    "AllowRead": false,
    "Ecosystem": "resource:org.example.empty.Ecosystem#7758",
    "Addsup": "resource:org.example.empty.Addsup#2534"
}
```

Now,I want to change the value of 'AllowRead' attribute through a transaction function.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

There are some simple example transactions that update a single field in the Composer Samples.

The 'Trade' transaction in the trade-network sample, and the 'Reject' transaction in the letters-of-credit-network.

You can find the samples from GitHub, or by using the [Composer online playground](https://composer-playground.mybluemix.net).

If you are new to Composer, I would suggest working through the Playground tutorial, and the Developer tutorial from the [Composer Tutorials page](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/tutorials).

Answer (score 1):

First you need to get the [registry](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/v0.19/api/runtime-assetregistry) for the asset:

```js
const registry = await getAssetRegistry('org.example.empty.userData');
```

Now [get](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/v0.19/api/runtime-assetregistry#get) the asset by the ID:

```js
const asset = await registry.get('3890');
```

Change the attributes and save the asset:

```js
asset.AllowRead = true;
await registry.update(asset);
```

Beware that both `get` and `update` are asynchronous functions, so either use `await` in an `async` function, or use the `Promise.then` syntax, e.g.

```js
getAssetRegistry('org.example.empty.userData')
    .then(registry => registry.get('3890'))
    .then(asset => {
        asset.AllowRead = true;
        return asset;
    })
    .then(asset => registry.update(asset));
```

If you are changing the attributes inside the tests, use the registry factory to access the registries:

```js
const factory = businessNetworkConnection.getBusinessNetwork().getFactory();
const registry = await factory.getAssetRegistry('org.example.empty.userData'); // etc
```